# Hive: numRows tblpropery shows wrong count

Tags: hive, hiveql

```
create table temp TBLPROPERTIES('numRows'='-1') as select * from test_table limit 10;
show tblproperties temp("numRows");
=> 1

insert into table temp select * from test_table limit 10;
show tblproperties temp("numRows");
=> 11 (10 + 1(earlier)
```

If I use insert query then it updates `numRows` properly.
Why this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to update the table statistics you have to run a `INSERT OVERWRITE STATEMENT`when you insert your data or after insert your data run `ANALYZE TABLE YOURDB.YOURTABLE COMPUTE STATISTICS`.

Here the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/StatsDev#StatsDev-ExistingTables%E2%80%93ANALYZE)